How to create a Python object that represents a simple hierarchy of self-typed children
I have a simple class in mind, called Page. Page has an ID and a Title.  Page can also have child Page's stored in the Page's children attribute.
I thought about doing this:

class Page:
  def __init__(self, id: int, title: str):
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.children = list[Page]

  def add_child(self, child: Page):  # Python doesn't like type hint of "Page"
    self.children.append(child)

2 questions:

Do I have the children attribute done right?  It is supposed to be a list of other Page's.
How can I provide the proper type hint in add_child?

Would love to learn if there are other suggestions for this kind of pattern.
EDIT:
Currently, add_child gives the following error:
TypeError: descriptor 'append' for 'list' objects doesn't apply to a 'Page' object


have you tested your code at all? Note for type hints of a class within a class, you can use either a string "forward reference", e.g. child: "Page" or use from __future__ import annotations (this whole sitaution is a bit of a mess in the python type-hinting system

think hard about what self.children = list[Page] does...

Which version are you running?

Running on Python 3.12. Current code throws an error on add_child. Will post that as soon as I get back in front of the computer.
Also, @juanpa.arrivillaga, what did you want to indicate?

list[Page] doesn't create a new list. Either [], list() or list[Page]() does. The latter is using new-ish generic typing.
